# R: Problems with copula due to safeUroot function not found.

Tags: r

I am trying to fit a copula with a script I have used many times before, but suddenly I get an error because of a function safeUroot. It says the function is not found, even if it appears to be defined. CAn anyone help and explain why I get this error and how I can overcome this. This only appears when fitting the Frank copula - other copulas seem to work.

```
> FrankFit = fitCopula(archmCopula("frank"), pseudo)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : could not find function "safeUroot"
> safeUroot
function (f, interval, ..., lower = min(interval), upper = max(interval), 
    f.lower = f(lower, ...), f.upper = f(upper, ...), Sig = NULL, 
    check.conv = FALSE, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.25, maxiter = 1000, 
    trace = 0) 
{
    if (is.null(Sig) && f.lower * f.upper > 0 || is.numeric(Sig) && 
        (Sig * f.lower > 0 || Sig * f.upper < 0)) {
        if (trace) 
            cat(sprintf("search in [%g,%g]%s", lower, upper, 
                if (trace >= 2) 
                  "\n"
                else " ... "))
        Delta <- function(u) 0.01 * pmax(1e-07, abs(u))
        if (is.null(Sig)) {
            delta <- Delta(c(lower, upper))
            while (isTRUE(f.lower * f.upper > 0) && any(iF <- is.finite(c(lower, 
                upper)))) {
                if (iF[1]) 
                  f.lower <- f(lower <- lower - delta[1])
                if (iF[2]) 
                  f.upper <- f(upper <- upper + delta[2])
                if (trace >= 2) 
                  cat(sprintf(" .. modified lower,upper: (%15g,%15g)\n", 
                    lower, upper))
                delta <- 2 * delta
            }
        }
        else {
            delta <- Delta(lower)
            while (isTRUE(Sig * f.lower > 0)) {
                f.lower <- f(lower <- lower - delta)
                if (trace) 
                  cat(sprintf(" .. modified lower: %g\n", lower))
                delta <- 2 * delta
            }
            delta <- Delta(upper)
            while (isTRUE(Sig * f.upper < 0)) {
                f.upper <- f(upper <- upper + delta)
                if (trace) 
                  cat(sprintf(" .. modified upper: %g\n", upper))
                delta <- 2 * delta
            }
        }
        if (trace && trace < 2) 
            cat(sprintf("extended to [%g, %g]\n", lower, upper))
    }
    if (!isTRUE(f.lower * f.upper <= 0)) 
        stop("did not succeed extending the interval endpoints for f(lower) * f(upper) <= 0")
    if (check.conv) {
        r <- tryCatch(uniroot(f, ..., lower = lower, upper = upper, 
            f.lower = f.lower, f.upper = f.upper, tol = tol, 
            maxiter = maxiter), warning = function(w) w)
        if (inherits(r, "warning")) 
            stop("convergence problem in zero finding: ", r$message)
        else r
    }
    else uniroot(f, ..., lower = lower, upper = upper, f.lower = f.lower, 
        f.upper = f.upper, tol = tol, maxiter = maxiter)
}
<bytecode: 0x000000004464ff18>
<environment: namespace:copula>
>
```

As mentioned, this has worked many times before, but stopped working today.

Comment: Did you recently upgrade R? If yes, did you run `update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE)`?

Comment: No, I did not recently upgrade R. Moreoever, I was able to fit other copulas (which I assume use the same function).